# Android studio stopped detecting Android devices but recognizes iOS devices

Tags: flutter, android-studio

This could look to be a very common question asked several times already, but my case seems to be different from what I've read on similar questions. Till last week, Android studio was detecting all devices and emulators (including iOS and Android), but suddenly it seem to have stopped detecting only Android, while iOS (simulator and physical device) are detected properly. Below are the details:

I am using Macbook Pro and my Android Studio is up-to-date, ie, 4.1.3. I've one physical Android device and an emulator connected and `adb` is recognizing it properly, as below:

[image]

My bash profile seems to be correct and pointing to `Android/sdk` properly.

But when I run `flutter doctor -v`, the command seems to completely ignore Android Studio and doesn't display its entry, as below:

[image]

As you can see, it's only showing desktop and web as connected devices, although I already have Android device and emulator connected too.

Moreover, If I open iOS simulator, the IDE immediately recognizes it and shows in the list, as:

[image]

And in `flutter doctor -v` properly:

[image]

I am not sure where exactly the issue could be and how to fix in order to make Android Studio show up Android devices too.
Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

=====update===

bash_profile and zshell is as below:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/dhs/documents/Fluttersdk/flutter/bin"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dhs/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues where I had iOS running but couldn't access Android. Here are things that worked for me -

1. If you have Docker engine running on your Mac, quit it. There are times when adb servers (the Android emulators) don't play well with Docker running concurrently on the system.
2. If emulator is non-responsive: Android Studio > Tools > AVD Manager > In the launch options for specific device, click "Cold Boot Now"
3. It might help to kill and restart the android emulator -

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell for certain that the `$PATH` is broken.

Replace `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` with `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` and then delete the obsolete directory `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` ...alike this you will run the current version of the `emulator` and not some rather outdated version (no clue when this changed, but it definitely changed).

The `$PATH` to the current version of the `emulator` should be:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Running `emulator --version` should return something alike `30.5.4.0`.

Comment: Tried this but still no luck. Since I am on Catalina, does it have to do with zshell or bash ? Although I've identical entries in both. Also edited my original post to reflect the same. Could there be anything missing under $ANDROID_HOME path ?

Comment: You have the wrong path to the `emulator` ...this has changed, while your `$PATH` hasn't - assuming you have the current version of the `emulator` installed, but run the leftover files from an outdated install... the directory most definitely is `/emulator` now. There may be further issues, but this would be an improvement to start with - which might eventually provide better Catalina support. Just run `emulator --version` before and after the change of `$PATH` to see the version number change.

Comment: I also think (if I remember that correctly) that uninstalling and the reinstalling the emulator with the SDK manager would make the `$PATH` more obviously break (it cannot find the new binary executable in `/emulator`) than just running the leftover files (it finds the outdated binary executable in `/tools`). The problem with the `$PATH` should become quite obvious when comparing the version the SDK manager shows with the version that `emulator --version` shows.